# Vis.js subgroups falling off the group and overlaping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I created a timeline in vis.js and added items, groups and subgroups.
I am adding the subgroup as a vis item with background type. 
When zooming in or moving the timeline left and right at certain zoom levels, the subgroups (which are background item type) fall off the assigned group and into the next group and overlap with the items in that group, which can be background or standard item type.

```
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, groups, options)
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/malii_constantin/96yuhtLd/

Normal(good) display:
[Good subgroup rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXM6X.png)

Bad subgroups:
[Zoomed one level in. Subgroup/item sg3 falls into next group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJmTp.png)

Anyone can help to fix this so that they display properly?